# How to check for malware before downloading a torrent file?

Tags: malware, antimalware

I wanted to know if there is a way to check if a torrent file has malware or not, before actually downloading it via uTorrent f.e.

I only know VirusTotal site. Is this one reliable? Because each time I past a link in it, it says that the link/file is safe. So I don't know if every single link/file I paste on virustotal is clear and safe or just the web doesn't detect malware well.

Best option for me would be to have a way to check it on the web without downloading 3rd party apps.

Comment: probably the best/only thing you can do is to check comments posted about that particular torrent... the community will sometimes call out torrents with viruses.   (and of course scan everything you download from the internet before opening/executing...)

Comment: Why do you want to check it before downloading?

Comment: .torrent file is just a binary encoded file using Bencode. It encodes metadata of torrents as a dictionary. There's no possibility of embedded malware in it unless it is carefully crafted attack which is exploiting a unpatched vulnerability in a particular torrent client. Most of the time, .torrent file is not even used. Simply clicking a magnet link is enough to start torrent.

Comment: You can use the tool https://torrent-file-editor.github.io/ and do the analysis by your self with it

Comment: I think when OP refers to "downloading a torrent file", they don't refer to the small file containing metadata, but the actual file described by the .torrent file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the reputation of the site or the comments of the file. As someone told you in comments, unless someone is using a day 0 attack or and unpatched vulnerability you will be safe. You can't do anything more **before** you download the torrent.

If you wanna check if the torrent has any kind of malware **after** the download, you should have a sandbox tool and a VM(Virtual Machine) or a dedicated computer for check the files you have downloaded. You can use an antivirus, antimalware bytes, roguekiller... After that, you can upload the files to virustotal and see if one the antivirus detect something in your files.

Comment: There should be an online service that lets you check a torrent for malware, they could limit one torrent per day per IP (and email confirmation) to avoid abuse, heck, some people would pay for that service, I think.